# Не могу скачать pip для python версии 3.2

Tags: python

Здравствуйте подскажите как скачать модуль pip для версии python 3.2.
Если есть версии питона которые смогут работать на windows xp с автоматически установленным pip скиньте их пожалуйста

Comment: Python 3.4 - последняя версия, которая работает на Windows XP. "Скиньте пожалуйста" - на python.org все есть, pip должен входить в поставку. Если нет, пробуйте устанавливать через get-pip или ensurepip, как тут описано: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: спасибо за совет